# XNA in IIS7 (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, xna

I'm working on a asp.net application that contains image which is very processing heavy to generate, but at the same time can't be pre-generated since it requires a lot of parameters and data from SQL Server. I decide to use XNA and process the image on GPU and from a few minutes processing on CPU with GDI+ I mange to get the time down to 1 sec using shaders.
Visual Web Developer was really nice to not give me any troubles when developing the site but once I tried to put it on IIS the nightmare started. After 2 days fighting with it I finally have XNA assembly loaded correctly but GraphicsAdapter.Adapters returns empty array.

**What prevents XNA from working in IIS?**

I tried my site on the same machine with IIS 7.5 express and it works just fine, but the express server is for local use only. On the same machine the website also works directly from Visual Web Developer.

The way I understand it IIS just don't have access to the graphics adapters which is really sad not being able to use GPU for parallel processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under which account is your ASP.Net process running?

this is just a hunch:  Your XNA code probably needs an interactive Windows session to get access to GraphicsAdapter info.

I guess you could try to configure the IIS service to allow it to "interact with desktop" (that's a checkbox in the Windows Service properties dialog).

Comment: I was so excited to try it out but no luck... Do I have to do something for this change to apply? I restarted the IIS service only.

Comment: I think a restart should be fine.  If you can, see which values the `System.Environment.UserInteractive` and `System.Environment.UserName` properties hold when your XNA app is being executed.

Again, I have no idea if runing in _iteractive_ mode will help you out, so I'm not promising anything!  I'm just curious to see if it helps :)

Comment: I finally had some time to mess with this again. System.Environment.UserInteractive is false :( although "Allow service to interact with desktop" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Why it's not working, I don't know. I'm not a big IIS or XNA guy.

I can suggest a workaround though:

You could have the XNA work as a separate program with input parameters. IIS could call that program the same way it would any other program. Then you can read the image in and display it as normal.

Comment: I had that option but my ASP already have all the SQL DB connections and stuff required for some other data on the site. If I make this in stand alone application I either have to implement all the SQL stuff inside that application or I have to pipe a massive amount of data to it. Which will probably have to be through a file.

Comment: Piping lots of data in shouldn't be a problem. It's a stream. Exporting to a file would be slower, but probably not too much so. It probably wouldn't take long to implement, and you could always implement and optimize if you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

It may be just a security issue. If you are running on your developer machine, try to configure application pool to run with administrative previliges and see what will happen.